# how to know if a user is logging in with their Facebook account in my website for the first time

Tags: facebook, authentication

I want to let users to log in with their facebook account but I wanna know when the users are logging in to my website for the first time. so I can save their facebook id and name into my database

Answer (score 1):

When you log the user into your site, you should do a lookup in your database to see if you already have that user saved - if you don't have them saved it's a new user, and you should save the details.